# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
#encoding=utf-8#

import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = open('datalist.txt','r')
a = file.readlines()
file.close()
data = [lines.split('\t') for lines in a]
# read the rainfall data

file = open('lonlat.txt','r')
b = file.readlines()
file.close()
lonlat = [lines.split('\t') for lines in b]
# read the lon, lat data

main_data = []
for d_a in data:
    for l_b in lonlat:
        if d_a[2] == l_b[0]:
            main_data.append(d_a + l_b[1:])
# integrate them

numcols, numrows = len(main_data[0]), len(main_data)

Lon = [m_a[4] for m_a in main_data]
Lat = [m_a[5] for m_a in main_data]
z = [m_a[3] for m_a in main_data] # define the lon, lat and rainfall

xi = np.linspace(22, 23, 102)
yi = np.linspace(113, 115, 102)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

x, y, z = Lon, Lat, z
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
im = ax.contour(xi, yi, zi, colors = 'black', linewidth = 0.2)
im = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi)
ax.scatter(Lon, Lat, c=z, s=50,
           vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max())
fig.colorbar(im)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
```

Here's my code. By reading the rainfall data and Lon, lat data and by integrating them, I am going to draw a contour. However, when I run the code, an error occurs:

```
C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py:1514: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  self.zmax = float(z.max())
C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py:1515: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  self.zmin = float(z.min())
C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py:1153: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return lev[(lev > zmin) & (lev < zmax)]
C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py:1153: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return lev[(lev > zmin) & (lev < zmax)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python脚本\meteotest.py", line 41, in <module>
    im = ax.contour(xi, yi, zi, colors = 'black', linewidth = 0.2)
  File "C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5825, in contour
    contours = mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 865, in __init__
    self._process_levels()
  File "C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1199, in _process_levels
    self.vmin = np.amin(self.levels)
  File "C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2372, in amin
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15432\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 29, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

I am quite confused about the value error raised. What does it mean? How can I fix the problem? Can anyone help me figure that out? Thanks in advance.

sample rainfall data:

```
    1   蛇口  蛇口码头    116.3
2   新安  新安  100.9
3   粤海  大冲  98.2
4   福保  福田  95.1
5   沙头  沙头  94.4
6   华富  笔架山 94.3
7   桂园  蔡屋围基地   91.6
8   招商  西部通道    90.9
9   招商  东角头 88.5
10  香蜜湖 安托山东    86.8
11  新安  西乡码头    86.2
12  香蜜湖 农园  86.1
13  南园  南园  84.2
14  笋岗  笋岗  83.5
15  莲花  莲花山 83.2
16  南湖  罗湖口岸    80.8
17  龙华  龙华  80.1
18  南山  南山  78.1
19  新安  宝安  76.2
20  东门  桂园  74.9
21  新安  宝安公园    74.3
22  香蜜湖 竹子林 73.7
23  南山  妈湾港 73.3
24  沙河  世界之窗    72.4
25  大浪  大浪  71.5
26  坂田  坂田  71.4
27  招商  左炮台 70.4
28  横岗  龙口水库    67.9
29  南澳  七星湾 65.1
30  民治  民治  63.3
31  清水河 清水河 62.7
32  西乡  西乡  61.6
33  梅林  梅林水库    61.5
34  横岗  六约  59.5
35  横岗  龙口  59.3
36  坪山  田头  58.9
37  西丽  西丽  57.1
38  石岩  石岩基地    56
39  西乡  黄麻布水库   54.9
40  平湖  白泥坑 54.9
41  坪山  江岭  54
42  南湾  南湾  53.8
43  福永  福永  52.6
44  横岗  横岗  49.9
45  西丽  大勘  49.8
46  光明  圳美  48.4
47  横岗  大康  48.4
48  坪山  坪山  47.2
49  坪山  沙湖  46
50  葵涌  坝光  45.7
51  光明  塘家  45.2
52  沙井  沙井  44.6
53  福永  深圳机场    42.6
54  石岩  石岩水库    42
55  坪地  坪西  41.9
56  葵涌  葵涌  40.3
57  公明  东方  40.1
58  坑梓  坑梓  39.4
59  石岩  石岩  39.3
60  光明  光明  39.2
61  观湖  观湖  37.2
62  葵涌  葵新  37.1
63  福永  和平  37
64  横岗  荷坳  36.9
65  黄贝  罗湖  36.7
66  布吉  布吉  36.2
67  沙井  海上田园    34.7
68  龙岗  龙岗  34.4
69  平湖  平湖  34.2
70  莲塘  莲塘  33.6
71  黄贝  罗芳  32.1
72  龙城  黄龙湖水库   32
73  坪地  坪地  31.9
74  南澳  南澳渔港    30.7
75  松岗  罗田水库    30.7
76  松岗  燕川  30.6
77  沙头角 沙头角 30.4
78  大鹏  大鹏  29.8
79  南澳  柚柑湾 29.5
80  松岗  松岗  29
81  盐田  明珠  28.3
82  南澳  南澳  28.2
83  东湖  深圳水库    28.1
84  观澜  牛湖  26.7
85  葵涌  土洋  24.9
86  葵涌  溪涌  24.5
87  梅沙  大梅沙 22.9
88  坪山  竹坑  21.9
89  大鹏  核电站 20.3
90  南澳  西涌  18.8
91  公明  公明  17.7
92  大鹏  龙岐  16.7
93  盐田  三洲田 13.6
94  南头  南头  10.6
95  梅沙  背仔角 9.6
96  盐田  盐田港 7.4
97  东湖  梧桐村 4.8
98  桃源  大学城 0
99  梅沙  小梅沙 0
```

sample lon, lat data:

```
    站名  经度  纬度
深圳机场北   113.8016667 22.66055556
和平  113.7883333 22.69305556
求雨坛 113.8455556 22.64694444
深圳机场南   113.8038889 22.62361111
福永  113.8175    22.67416667
深圳机场    113.8011111 22.66083333
立新水库    113.8066667 22.68638889
海上田园    113.7672222 22.72333333
海上田园    113.7672222 22.72305556
长流陂水库   113.8686111 22.71888889
共和  113.7980556 22.755
沙井  113.8197222 22.72833333
石龙仔 113.9702778 22.70027778
石岩基地    113.8941667 22.65361111
石岩水库    113.8980556 22.70472222
石岩基地    113.8936111 22.65388889
石岩  113.9347222 22.68472222
燕川  113.8602778 22.80166667
罗田水库    113.8736111 22.83694444
松岗  113.8361111 22.77916667
老虎坑 113.8388889 22.83194444
细丫岛 113.8188889 22.54722222
铁仔山 113.8555556 22.59777778
黄麻布水库   113.8622222 22.66722222
后瑞  113.83  22.63083333
西乡码头    113.8438889 22.56055556
西乡  113.8372222 22.60916667
铁岗水库    113.885 22.61277778
宝安公园    113.8930556 22.58861111
宝安  113.9061111 22.56277778
新安  113.8797222 22.55277778
大鹏  114.47  22.60055556
核电站 114.5505556 22.59694444
龙岐  114.5002778 22.56944444
葵新  114.4319444 22.61888889
官湖  114.4191667 22.60583333
罗屋田水库   114.4433333 22.65083333
径心水库    114.4505556 22.62722222
溪涌  114.3561111 22.61
土洋  114.3922222 22.615
葵涌  114.415 22.63361111
坝光  114.5144444 22.64555556
柚柑湾 114.4861111 22.48277778
东涌  114.5691667 22.49638889
七娘山 114.5455556 22.52888889
桔钓沙 114.5572222 22.56
南澳渔港    114.4844444 22.53444444
天文台 114.5575    22.48333333
西涌基地    114.5583333 22.48277778
西涌  114.5263889 22.48138889
南澳  114.4786111 22.54166667
七星湾 114.5352778 22.56194444
福田  114.0491667 22.525
水围  114.0613889 22.52222222
笔架山 114.0708333 22.56861111
华强北 114.0830556 22.55027778
莲 花 山   114.0575    22.55277778
梅林水库    114.0291667 22.5725
上梅林 114.0530556 22.5775
南园  114.0955556 22.5375
红树林 114.0302778 22.51611111
红树林 114.0305556 22.51583333
沙头  114.0163889 22.53027778
农园  114.0141667 22.54888889
安托山东    114.0094444 22.56055556
竹子林基地   114.0047222 22.54138889
竹子林 114.0047222 22.54138889
八卦岭 114.09  22.56305556
公明  113.8911111 22.78166667
东方  113.8788889 22.74388889
铁坑水库    113.9041667 22.815
塘家  113.9658333 22.735
光明  113.9536111 22.7625
育新学校    113.9558333 22.74166667
圳美  113.9544444 22.79472222
细靓北 114.0908333 22.62055556
布吉  114.1122222 22.60555556
六约  114.1694444 22.63694444
大康  114.2236111 22.64638889
横岗  114.1933333 22.64638889
荷坳  114.2338889 22.68527778
龙口水库    114.1794444 22.66222222
黄阁坑 114.2116667 22.71166667
龙口  114.195 22.67944444
黄龙湖水库   114.2361111 22.76583333
龙岗  114.2422222 22.72416667
龙岗基地    114.2108333 22.69
双龙  114.2777778 22.72861111
南湾  114.1488889 22.61638889
上李朗 114.1127778 22.65972222
坪地  114.3044444 22.7775
坪西  114.2622222 22.76694444
白泥坑 114.1508333 22.65611111
平湖  114.1230556 22.69611111
坂田  114.07  22.63083333
大浪  114.0025    22.68305556
福城  113.9983333 22.72861111
观湖  114.0397222 22.70777778
牛湖  114.0822222 22.72722222
清湖  114.045 22.67083333
龙华  114.0141667 22.65888889
民治  114.0291667 22.62305556
民治水库    114.0477778 22.61138889
翠竹  114.1277778 22.56111111
梧桐村 114.1880556 22.595
深圳水库    114.1436111 22.57166667
小梧桐 114.19  22.57111111
大梧桐 114.2138889 22.585
东门  114.0613889 22.52222222
草埔  114.1116667 22.58805556
蔡屋围基地   114.1038889 22.54722222
桂园  114.1047222 22.54972222
蔡屋围基地   114.1033333 22.54777778
罗芳  114.1508333 22.55166667
罗湖  114.1266667 22.55083333
莲塘  114.1658333 22.56472222
罗湖口岸    114.1133333 22.53083333
清水河 114.1011111 22.57194444
笋岗  114.1119444 22.55916667
13-1平台  116.1566667 21.5875
11-1平台  115.7   20.83138889
30-1平台  114.9411111 20.24444444
南山  113.9202778 22.53
妈湾港 113.8686111 22.495
南头  113.9147222 22.5475
世界之窗    113.9691667 22.53916667
蛇口码头    113.9088889 22.48
孖洲岛 113.845 22.49805556
大学城 113.9727778 22.59638889
桃源  113.9722222 22.56055556
大勘  113.9680556 22.62055556
塘朗山 113.9991667 22.59388889
西丽  113.9338889 22.605
第二高中    113.9305556 22.57222222
大冲  113.9469444 22.55111111
海珠  113.9472222 22.5225
东角头 113.9308333 22.48861111
西部通道    113.9447222 22.50388889
左炮台 113.8855556 22.47
松子坑水库   114.3427778 22.73527778
坑梓  114.3663889 22.745
田头  114.3997222 22.69583333
竹坑  114.3552778 22.7125
沙湖  114.3002778 22.67888889
江岭  114.3625    22.67166667
坪山  114.3405556 22.69444444
移动气象站A  #VALUE! #VALUE!
三门岛 114.6286111 22.46055556
移动气象台   #VALUE! #VALUE!
移动气象站B  #VALUE! #VALUE!
前海  113.8925    22.52472222
海山  114.2325    22.55777778
东部华侨城   114.2927778 22.62527778
大梅沙 114.2975    22.60083333
背仔角 114.3372222 22.59527778
背仔角 114.3366667 22.59555556
小梅沙 114.3247222 22.60555556
沙头角 114.2238889 22.555
正坑水库    114.2122222 22.55888889
三洲田 114.2672222 22.60083333
明珠  114.2430556 22.58388889
盐田港 114.2752778 22.56666667
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run that reproduces the error? I suspect it's due to `NaN` or masked values in `zi`, but it's impossible to tell from here.

Comment: One possible solution to test would be to replace `xi, yi, zi` with `xi[~np.isnan(zi)], yi[~np.isnan(zi)], zi[~np.isnan(zi)]`

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: We need to be able to copy-paste this into a Python interpreter and run it, which we currently can't. That's not a useable form of example data. Have you checked that this example data actually produces that error?

Comment: Actually the original data contains about 102 sets of data, but I now have only three listed here. It seems to be impossible to update my original txt.

Comment: I have just updated my original text data, though it contains bunch of Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

With a reasonable `zi` I get a nice contour plot:

```
In [366]: xi,yi = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(8))
In [367]: zi = xi*yi
In [368]: fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
In [369]: ax.contour(xi,yi,zi)
Out[369]: <matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet at 0xa959aeec>
```

But if all values a `nan` I get your error message:

```
In [371]: wi=zi*np.nan
In [372]: ax.contour(xi,yi,wi)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:1514: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  self.zmax = float(z.max())
...
---> 29     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
     30 
     31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

I don't know if a smaller set of `nan` values does it as well or not.  In any case, check your `zi` for `nan` values.  Even if the `z` values look good, the `griddata` interpolation could be having problems, resulting in lots or all `nan`.

You may have to try other interpolation methods.  See the `griddata` docs.

---

The error occurs when it tries to calculate the `levels`. Presumably it removes `nan's` and then takes the min/max.  If `levels` is given as a parameter, we still get the warnings, but no error.

```
In [390]: ax.contour(xi,yi,wi,levels=[0,1])
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:1514: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  self.zmax = float(z.max())
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:1515: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  self.zmin = float(z.min())
Out[390]: <matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet at 0xa934ef0c>
```

Comment: I have checked and printed out my z data, where it shows:  ['116.3\n', '100.9\n', '98.2\n', '95.1\n'...etc.] Does the "\n" affect the reading of my data? Plus, changing the levels to a parameter is OK, but a graph still cannot be drew.

Comment: Those are strings, not numbers.

Comment: So I have to convert the strings to numbers? But when I apply the convert method, it goes either like this "ValueError: could not convert string to float" or "[['116.3'], ['100.9'], ..., etc., ['0']]" which is definitely not what I want. I know this might be a stupid problem, but I just cannot fix it out lol